# Hyper-V Sockets in 2016 version and host/guest communication

Tags: windows, virtualization, windows-10, windows-server

In new version of Hyper-V released recently with MS Windows Server 2016 contains a new functionality [Hyper-V Sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/develop/make_mgmt_service?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which allows for host/guest communication.

It uses WinSock API with new address family AF_HYPERV.

I am no a security expert however would like to use this new functionality in public cloud platform developed with my involvement as it seems a very good way to have two way communication between host and guest (e.g. for provisioning, monitoring, etc.)

What should I look out for when using this functionality and are there any known architectural or other security issues with it ? I'm worried about guest gaining access to host in any unauthorised way.

Comment: My _guess_ is that the biggest risk would be exploitable bugs in the protocol.